# AT+CSQ network percentage formula from rssi

Tags: math, formula, gsm, at-command, rssi

Does anyone knows **formula for calculating GSM network coverage into percents (0 .. 100) from rssi**? It should be safe for 8bit AVR microcontroller CPU, without hardcore math operations like log or division by something that's not 2^n (bitshift is preferred). Creating array with 32 possible percentage values is poor solution.

possible rssi values (0..31 is valid values):

```
0 -113 dBm or less
1 -111 dBm
2...30 -109... -53 dBm
31 -51 dBm or greater
99 not known or not detectable
```

Approximate values i want:

```
RSSI    %
0   0
1   3
2   6
3   10
4   13
5   16
6   19
7   23
8   26
9   29
10  32
11  36
12  39
13  42
14  45
15  48
16  52
17  55
18  58
19  61
20  65
21  68
22  71
23  74
24  78
25  81
26  84
27  87
28  90
29  94
30  97
31  100
99  ?
```

I'm out of ideas, so please advise me! Thanks for Your time!

Answer (score 6):

(rssi * 827 + 127) >> 8

Multiply by 827, add 127 to simulate rounding to nearest, then drop the 8 low order bits, all in integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately not a simple task to do if you want it to be accurate.

This article best explains the complexities of the task:
https://www.adriangranados.com/blog/dbm-to-percent-conversion

Answer (score 0):

Without involving floats: RSSI*3+3 will miss high and low values, but will be OK mid-range. If accuracy at high values is more important add more than 3 and vice versa.